# Access Instance Variables in Another Method in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a GUI in Java. One method initializes and displays a form:

```
public class launchQMBPMN extends CytoscapeAction {
  private JComboBox termDB;

  public launchQMBPMN(QMBPMN SaddleSum) {
    super("SaddleSum");
    setPreferredMenu("Plugins");


  }

  public class buttonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      JFrame hello = new JFrame();
      JLabel test = new JLabel(termDB.getSelectedItem());
      test.add(hello);
      hello.show();
    }
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CytoscapeDesktop desktop = Cytoscape.getDesktop();

    InteractionTools tools = new InteractionTools();

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    c.weightx = 0.5;

    buttonListener buttonPressed = new buttonListener();

    // TERM DATABASE AND WEIGHTS

    JPanel qmbpTermsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    termDB = new JComboBox(tools.discoverTermDatabases());
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    qmbpTermsPanel.add(termDB, c);  


                ...
```

I'd like to access 'termDB' in my buttonListner class. How do I do that?

Comment: You can do `CytoscapeAction.this.termDB`

Comment: @Falmarri: That's already overcomplicated.

Comment: By the way, you should, by convention, make class names CamelCase with a big letter at the beginning and variable names start lowercase.

Comment: @thejh: It's clearer, and sometimes necessary in case there's a local name masking the outer class's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it as you posted here. Some comments:

1. `show` method of `JFrame` (actually, of `java.awt.Window`) is deprecated, use `setVisible(true);` instead.
2. I'm not sure `test.add(hello);` is that you really need. Is it? It adds the frame to the label.
3. `termDB.getSelectedItem()` returns an `Object`, `JLabel` constructor requires a string: `termDB.getSelectedItem().toString()`?

Comment: You've managed to preemptively hit everything I was trying to figure out after this bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply access it using its name, that should work as it's inside the outer class.

See also: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: Don't I feel silly. When I was getting the symbol not found error the compiler was referring to the getSelectedItem() method and not termDB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of ButtonListener and pass the termDB into it when you create it, or otherwise set it.

Or you can can define an anonymous inner class where need the button listener and make termDB final, and it will be available in your ButtonListener implementation.  Or you could pass the termDB reference to the anonymous inner classs like you would in the first option I presented.